# install mysql-python using pip on mac os

Tags: python, macos

When I install `mysql-python` using `pip` on mac os, I always get this error, how can I solve this problem?

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/BuildRoot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.Internal.sdk/usr/local/libressl/lib'
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-UEOYdV/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-UEOYdV/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-EgQ8P0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: That appears to be the system install of Python, you **really** shouldn’t mess with it. Use virtual environments or similar alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: This is exactly right and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [AMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11301900/amc) posted in a comment, this error can occur when using the builtin MacOS Python 2. Use a tool like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to install a standard Python distribution, create a virtual environment, and try again.